# Dynamically editing multiple identical HTML forms with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am building a small webpage that is will be used to control a set of RGB [LEDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode) with a predefined set actions. To configure the actions graphically, a form is used that contains the start and end pixel, relevant color information, and the set action to use.

(As an aside, the forms are *not* submitted, so if another structure would work better, it can be used instead. Forms support `name`, so that helps for at least *some* of it, though. JavaScript parses the data in the forms to a JSON file that's sent with Ajax later on. I've gotten that mostly figured out, but there *are* some parts where the issue I'm going to bring up complicates things in trying to read the data out of all the forms at once in a simply manner.)

Each form has some action (`onChange` of the dropdown that selects the action, or the delete button) that is supposed to affect that form (or parts of it) only. There is also supposed to be a way to get all the forms at once and extract the data to send to the server (which works fine using `name` since *that* data is safely contained in form-accessible elements).

I am also unable to use helper libraries like JQuery because there is no Internet access. All code must be hosted on the server, and space is rather minimal (it's an embedded processor hosting it). The 40KB of Jquery is not something I want to add right now.

The problem I'm having is that I need to change the label text and show or hide elements based on what option is selected.

For instance, a single color only needs ONE color input tag, but the linear fade needs two. Others need no colors, since they perform actions on existing color patterns.

Using a `form` allows things with the `name` attribute set to be accessed via looking up the form_as_JS_var.elements.name. Sadly, this does *not* work on raw HTML, or `span`s or really *anything* other than form-specific elements. I also found that `document.getElementById()` does not have an equivalent for things other than `document` (In case it's not obvious by this point, I am somewhat new to HTML and JavaScript). I had been hoping to do something like <form_var>.getElementById("color1") or something (which might let me use identical labels for simplicity so long as they weren't reused in each form, but it's kind of dumb in hindsight). Either way, I'd need to make sure that I include multiple *globally* unique IDs per each added form *and* **somehow** look up the ID, when the item being affected *and* the item triggering the change are in the same form!

I *did* discover the `label` tag, but it (for some *inexplicable* reason) binds to IDs and not names (and is really annoying to set up with JavaScript, but that's another story). I am thus still stuck with using globally-unique IDs accessed from `document` rather than any sort of form-local methods.

The HTML form I'd like to use is as follows:

```
<form id="color_form_0" class="color_form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend id="legend_0">New Control Entry</legend>
    <label for="legend_0">Type: </label>
      <select name="type" id="type_0">
        <option value="rainbow">Rainbow Pattern</option>
        <option value="repeat">Clone Fill</option>
        <option value="fade">Linear Fade</option>
        <option value="fill">Single Color</option>
        <option value="rotate">Animation</option>
      </select>
    <label for="color1_0">Color 1: </label>
      <input type="color" name="color1" id="color1_0">
    <label for="color2_0">Color 2: </label>
      <input type="color" name="color2" id="color2_0">
    <br>
    <label for="range1_0">Range Start: </label>
      <input type="number" max="80" min="0" id="range1_0">
    <label for="range2_0">Range End: </label>
      <input type="number" max="80" min="0" id="range2_0">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Note that a lot of it requires unique IDs (the _# section added on). I have to have GUIDs for the labels to even access them properly (no ID makes the label inaccessible, non-unique IDs make *all* of them bind equally to *every* item with that ID (across forms)). I also have to have an ID to change the name of the legend tag (which is supposed to change to match the currently-selected Type.

What I was expecting to be able to do was along the lines of:

```
<form>
  <button onclick="doStuff()">foo</button>
  <some_tag_here>
</form>
```

with JavaScript in *doStuff* that basically goes like this (may not be precisely accurate; read as pseudocode):

```
function doStuff(b){
  var par=b.parentNode;
  var otherTag=par.SomeHowGetOtherTagPerhapsByNonUniqueIdOrClassNameMightAlsoWork();
  otherTag.innerHtml="<blink>Success!!!</blink>";
```

Instead, I can access *some* items by `name`, but not all that I need to change, and the `label` tag, while seemingly perfect for this at first, must have unique IDs anyway.

The `name` method *does* allow this sort of tree-traverse, but it's not perfect. My other idea, childNode, is an array that I'm not sure how to search for the *one* node (or several) that I'd need to modify, and probably assumes that there's some sort of identifier in there already... like an Id again.

TL;DR:

I am trying to edit items in the same form that the button (or other element) triggered the function from. There are multiple forms, and I do not want to affect the others. I can capture `this` and get the parent of the button (the form, essentially) that holds the things I want to edit.

I cannot figure out how to efficiently or simply change any content in the form that is *not* a form-specific element (i.e., change simple text that tells the user something). All solutions I have found so far require doing a *global*-scale lookup which requires that *each* of the multiple forms has unique Ids on every element or those `label`-ed, and makes my sense of efficiency cringe when the data is right near the element looking for it.

The latter assumes that a document.getElementByX is more expensive than a hypothetical getParent.getChild-type operation (which is what I *want* to do), but for the sake of not getting headaches when coding, a more local approach would be nice even if that's not the case.

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique in the entire document. That's why there's no `container.getElementById()`. Use classes instead of IDs, then you can use `container.querySelector(".classname")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `querySelector()` method. It can be applied to a container and searches within that container.

```js
function doStuff(b){
  var par=b.parentNode;
  var otherTag=par.querySelector("div");
  otherTag.innerHTML="<span style='color: red;'>Success!!!</span>";
}
```

```html
<form>
  <button type="button" onclick="doStuff(this)">foo</button>
  <div></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Does that work for different types of items within the form? I have more than one `input` with different `type` settings, some of which are _also_ the same. If it does work with some sort of identifier, beyond the element type, but for something that only has to be unique within the form, it would be ideal.

Comment: Best practice is to use classes to distinguish types of items, then you can select the class with `querySelector(".classname")`

Comment: Alright, thanks. That sounds perfect for what I need, then.